# Firestore does not save line breaks from text area

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a text area with Vue v-model and saving it in a firestore collection. But the line breaks disappear in database.

How can it be fixed ?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea v-model="docsInfo" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
// ... JS
export default {
    data() {
        return {
          title: "",
          docsInfo: "",
        };
    },
// ...
db
    .collection("posts")
    .add({
      title: this.title,
      info: this.docsInfo // from text area
    })
```

Answer (score 11):

The line breaks don't appear in Firestore console and the text is shown as a single line, but they are saved.
Just apply the marked answer in the link below.
[Vue.js show white space (line breaks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178401/vue-js-show-white-space-line-breaks)